# Hyperbolic Functions via Circular Inversion

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, hyperbolic-functions

I was recently introduced to the concept of inversion in the plane, in which a circle of inversion is chosen so that all points $A$ that can be described relative to the center of inversion $O$ have dance partners $A’$, whose length from the center of inversion is related to they length of the original point from the center by $OA\cdot OA’ = R^2$.

I was wondering whether there is a means by which circular inversion may be used to derive the hyperbolic trigonometric functions, because the equation above is a rotated hyperbola. I am new to the subject so I would appreciate any thoughts you might have on this.

Comment: *"[...] because the equation above is a rotated hyperbola."* Well, not exactly. For a hyperbola, you'd want something like $OP\cdot OQ=R^2$, where $\overline{OP}$ and $\overline{OQ}$ are *perpendicular* segments. In an inversion construction, $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OA'}$ are *collinear*. That's not to say that you can't tease a hyperbola out of the inversion: eg, rotate $A$ by $90^\circ$ about $O$ to get, say, $B$; then the perpendicular to $\overline{OA'}$ at $A'$ meets the perpendicular to $\overline{OB}$ at $B$ in a point $P$ that traces a rectangular hyperbola as $A$ and $A'$ vary.